# Always Round UP a Double

Tags: java

How could I always round up a `double` to an `int`, and never round it down.
I know of `Math.round(double)`, but I want it to always round up.
So if it was `3.2`, it gets rounded to 4.

Comment: `Math.ceil` - if you have a problem like this in the future you can read the generated JavaDoc of the relevant library. In this case Math

Comment: Even if you didn't feel like RTFM, `Math.round(yourNum+0.5)` works.

Comment: @nhgrif Not quite as `0.0` will be rounded up to `1` this is the same as rounding down and adding 1.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `Math.ceil()` method.

See JavaDoc link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)

From the docs:

**ceil**

```
public static double ceil(double a)
```

Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer. Special cases:

- If the argument value is already equal to a mathematical integer, then the result is the same as the argument.
- If the argument is NaN or an infinity or positive zero or negative zero, then the result is the same as the argument.
- If the argument value is less than zero but greater than -1.0, then the result is negative zero.

Note that the value of Math.ceil(x) is exactly the value of -Math.floor(-x).

**Parameters:**

- a - a value.

**Returns:**

The smallest (closest to negative infinity) floating-point value that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

Comment: If you can quote from the link, it helps people find the entire answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: _ceil_ returns a _double_, he asked for _int_

Comment: @tabz100 I (and I am sure the OP too) used the word "int" as a java data-type, not a mathematical term. So a cast or something else that gives an _int_ is missing from the answer.

Answer (score 17):

In simple words,

- `Math.ceil` will always **round UP** or as said above, in **excess**.
- `Math.round` will round up or down depending on the decimals.

  - If the decimal is **equal or higher than 5**, then it's **rounded up**.

    - decimal => 5. (1,5 = 2)
  - If the decimal is **less than 5**, then it's **rounded down**.

    - decimal < 5. (1,45 = 1)

Examples of `Math.ceil` and `Math.round`:

The code Below would return:
Cost, without Ceil 2.2 and with Ceil 3 (int), 3.0 (double). If we round it: 2

```
    int m2 = 2200;
    double rate = 1000.0;

    int costceil = (int)Math.ceil(m2/rate);
    double costdouble = m2/rate;
    double costdoubleceil = Math.ceil(m2/rate);
    int costrounded = (int)Math.round(m2/rate);
    System.out.println("Cost, without Ceil "+costdouble+" and with Ceil "+
            costceil+"(int), "+costdoubleceil+"(double). If we round it: "+costrounded);
```

If we change the value of m2 to for example **2499**, the result would be:
Cost, without Ceil 2.499 and with Ceil 3 (int), 3.0 (double). If we round it: 2
If we change the value of m2 to for example **2550**, the result would be:
Cost, without Ceil 2.55 and with Ceil 3 (int), 3.0 (double). If we round it: 3

Hope it helps. (Information extracted from previous answers, i just wanted to make it clearer).

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
BigDecimal( "3.2" ).setScale( 0 , RoundingMode.CEILING )
```

> 4

## `BigDecimal`

If you want [accuracy rather than performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems), avoid [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) technology. That means avoiding `float`, `Float`, `double`, `Double`. For accuracy, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class.

On a `BigDecimal`, [set the scale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-), the number of digits to the right of the decimal place. If you want no decimal fraction, set scale to zero. And specify a [rounding mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html). To always round an fraction upwards, use [`RoundingMode.CEILING`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#CEILING), documented as:

> Rounding mode to round towards positive infinity. If the result is positive, behaves as for RoundingMode.UP; if negative, behaves as for RoundingMode.DOWN. Note that this rounding mode never decreases the calculated value. So for example, 1.1 becomes 2, and your 3.2 becomes 4.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( "3.2" ) ;
BigDecimal bdRounded = bd.setScale( 0 , RoundingMode.CEILING ) ;
String output = bdRounded.toString() ; 
System.out.println( "bdRounded.toString(): " + bdRounded ) ;  // 4
```

> 4

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/g1Rqxj).

Answer (score 0):

```
private int roundUP(double d){
    double dAbs = Math.abs(d);
    int i = (int) dAbs;
    double result = dAbs - (double) i;
    if(result==0.0){ 
        return (int) d;
    }else{
        return (int) d<0 ? -(i+1) : i+1;          
    }
}
```

Good job ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

My method is relatively simple, hope it works for you.

In my case I have a row of objects that can only hold 3 items and I must adjust the number of rows I have to accommodate the items.

So I have some Double numberOfRows, I then use numberOfRows.intValue() to get an int value for numberOfRows.

if the int value I get is less than numberOfRows, I add 1 to numberOfRows to round it up, else the value I get from numberOfRows.intValue() is the answer I want.

I wrote this simple for loop to test it out:

```
    for(int numberOfItems = 0; numberOfItems < 16; numberOfItems++) {
        Double numberOfRows = numberOfItems / 3.0;

        System.out.println("Number of rows are: " + numberOfRows);
        System.out.println("Number of items are: " + numberOfItems);
        if(numberOfRows.intValue() < numberOfRows) {
            System.out.println("int number of rows are: " + (numberOfRows.intValue() + 1));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("int value of rows are: " + numberOfRows.intValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short example without using *Math.ceil()*.

```
public double roundUp(double d){
    return d > (int)d ? (int)d + 1 : d;
}
```

**Exaplanation:**
Compare operand to rounded down operand using typecast, if greater return rounded down argument + 1 (means round up) else unchanged operand.

**Example in Pseudocode**

```
double x = 3.01
int roundDown = (int)x   // roundDown = 3
if(x > roundDown)        // 3.01 > 3
    return roundDown + 1 // return 3.0 + 1.0 = 4.0
else
    return x             // x equals roundDown
```

Anyway you should use `Math.ceil()`. This is only meant to be a simple example of how you could do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.ceil` did not work for me. It keeps rounding down when I cast back to `long`. Below is my hack:

```
long pages = (userCnt % size) == 0 ? (userCnt / size) : (userCnt / size) + 1;
```

Simply check if `Even` or `Odd` and if `Odd`, add `1` to the result.

Answer (score 0):

It is even much easier in Kotlin using **`kotlin.math.ceil`** in an extension function.

```
fun Double.roundUpDoubleToInt(): Int {
    return kotlin.math.ceil(this)
            .toInt()
}
```

These are the various returned results:

```
fun main() {
    val a = 3.5
    val b = 3.6
    val c = 3.1
    val d = 3.01
    val e = 3.0

    println(a.roundUpDoubleToInt()) //=> 4
    println(b.roundUpDoubleToInt()) //=> 4
    println(c.roundUpDoubleToInt()) //=> 4
    println(d.roundUpDoubleToInt()) //=> 4
    println(e.roundUpDoubleToInt()) //=> 3

}
```

Alternatively, you can always `round-off UP` or `round-off DOWN` with **`0.5`** being the cut-off i.e. round up if **`>= 0.5`** or round down if **`< 0.5`**.

This is the logic written in Kotlin.

```
fun Double.roundOffDoubleToInt():Int  {

    val intValue = this.toInt()
    val fractionValue = this - intValue


    return if (fractionValue >= 0.5) intValue +1 else intValue

}
```

These are the results:

```
fun main() {
    val a = 3.5
    val b = 3.6
    val c = 3.1
    val d = 3.01
    val e = 3.0

    println(a.roundOffDoubleToInt()) //=> 4
    println(b.roundOffDoubleToInt()) //=> 4
    println(c.roundOffDoubleToInt()) //=> 3
    println(d.roundOffDoubleToInt()) //=> 3
    println(e.roundOffDoubleToInt()) //=> 3
}
```

Cheers ....

Answer (score -3):

`Math.ceil()` will give you the closest lowest value if you want it to be rounded to largest closest values you should use `Math.floor()`

Comment: This is back to front.