# How to narrow down a rounding issue in a Java program?

Tags: java, casting, floating-point

```
public class Rest {        
    public static void main(String[] args) {           
        double mealCost;
        int tipPercent;
        int taxPercent;
        double totalCost;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        mealCost = scan.nextDouble();
        tipPercent = scan.nextInt();
        taxPercent = scan.nextInt();

        double tipInD = mealCost * (double)tipPercent / 100;
        double taxInD = mealCost * (double)taxPercent / 100;

        totalCost = (double)mealCost + (double)tipInD + (double)taxInD;

        System.out.println("The total meal cost is "+(int)totalCost+" dollars.");
    }
}
```

This is the program i have created and I have to pass 4 different input cases, 3 of which am passing with this code, but the fourth 1 am not able to.

input cases with expected o/p.

**Input for 1st - 3rd cases**

```
---------
12.00 20 8
----------
15.50 15 10
----------
20.75 10 3
```

**Output for 1st - 3rd cases**

```
---------
The total meal cost is 15 dollars.
---------
The total meal cost is 19 dollars.
---------
The total meal cost is 23 dollars.
```

For the 4th case, the code I have written is not able to give the wanted O/P for it.

**Input**

```
--------
10.25
17
5
```

**Output Should Be**

The total meal cost is 13 dollars. 
And am Getting The total meal cost is 12 dollars.

Comment: You're casting totalCost to int, you should output it as double

Comment: So what diagnostics have you used? Have you tried printing out `tipInD` and `taxInD`? Have you tried printing out `totalCost` without the cast to `int`?

Comment: `totalCost` is actually `12.504999999999999`. as casting is rounding down you will always get `12` here

Comment: I am not going to order at your place if you are rounding that much !! ;) leave the decimal. See how to limit the number of decimal if you want to only show 2.

Comment: How is this a good question? Just starting from the title, it says literally nothing about what the question is about. It is a debug-this-code-for-me request. No debugging attempts are described, nor is any troubleshooting of any kind. OP, please read [ask].

Comment: I just saw this on the HNQ lol

Comment: Pro tip for titles: narrow down what you actual problem is, and write a succinct title for it. Since it clear you're looking for help, "please help me" tends to be understood as begging, and that usually does not go down well. All questions are of equal importance here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Narrowing Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) :

- double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float

if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is **rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward zero** using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are two cases:

If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long, then the result of the first step is the long value V.

Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of the first step is the int value V.

---

```
(int)totalCost => (int) 12.504999999999999 => 12 (decimal part stripped)
```

Instead you may want to use `Math.round( totalCost )` to get the *closest integral value*.

```
Math.round( totalCost ) => Math.round( 12.504999999999999 ) => 13
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, from what you do expect, you just want to print:

```
System.out.println("The total meal cost is " + Math.round(totalCost) + " dollars.");
```

instead of.

```
System.out.println("The total meal cost is " +(int)totalCost + " dollars.");
```

The first one will properly round based on the mathematical rules, the second one will just stripe of the floating point values. That´s why the last one results in `12` and not `13`, because it doesn´t actually round.

Answer (score 2):

Change the way you write the `totalCost` to:

```
System.out.println("The total meal cost is "+ Math.round(totalCost) +" dollars.");
```

This will actually round off your output as per it should be calculated rather than just strip the decimal value directly.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution is changing your output to

```
System.out.println("The total meal cost is " + (int) Math.ceil(totalCost) + " dollars.");
```

Explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614695/always-round-up-a-double)

Answer (score 0):

You are casting an double value to an integer value. Note that by doing so you cut of the number at the decimal point and there is no rounding involved. Your calculation is `10.25*0.17 + 10.25*0.05 + 10.25 = 12.505`
By applying the cast you get 12 and not 13. Don't cast your value, and you will be fine.

Comment: You should add some formatting the math operation (code tag are ok for this) and also a solution to the problem. This would be a good answer